# Logical Implication Question

Tags: logic

> $A: \text{Humans are at most 12 feet tall}$
>
> $B: \text{Humans are at most 9 feet tall}$

Neither implies the other.  *A* contradicts *B* and *B* contradicts *A*.

Am I correct?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at the [square of opposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition). In logic terminology, two sentences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are said to be in a contradiction iff it is the case that $\alpha$ is true when $\beta$ is false and vice-versa, You can see that this is not the case. Particularly, *B* and *A* can be both false.

Comment: But am I right that A does not imply B and B does not imply A?

Comment: Yes, the sentences do not imply each other (they are contraries, so they cannot be both true, then, if you assume one the other will be always false. Hence both $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow A$ cannot be the case)

Comment: @akuryo No.  "Humans are at most $x$ feet tall" is not the same statement as "the tallest human is exactly $x$ feet tall".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern logic terminology, back from the Aristotelian doctrine of the [square of opposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/), two sentences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are said to be in a contradiction iff it is the case that $\alpha$ is true when $\beta$ is false and vice-versa, that is, $\alpha$ is false when $\beta$ is true.

This relation is found in both diagonals of the square:

[image]

Particularly, Two sentences are are

- **contradictory** iff they cannot both be true and they cannot both be false
- **contraries** iff they cannot both be true but can both be false.
- **subcontraries** iff they cannot both be false but can both be true.

Particularly, *B* and *A* can be both false simultaneously, what disqualifies their logical relation as a contradiction. Still, *B* and *A* cannot be simultaneously true. Hence, *B* and *A* are contraries.

---

Now in regard of your question as to whether

> *A* does not imply *B* and *B* does not imply *A*

Yes it is true. For the former, let humans be at most 12 feet tall. Then it follows humans are not at most 9 feet tall. For the latter, let humans be at most 9 feet tall. Then humans are not at most 12 feet tall.

Most importantly, *A* and *B* are **contraries**, so remember that they cannot be both true. Then, if you assume one the other will be always false. The conclusion of our analysis is that both $A→B$ and $B→A$ cannot be the case.

Comment: Ah, it was a trick question!  It asked as if it was one or the other, but it was neither.  That's a convenient diagram.  Thanks for showing it to me and thank you for helping.

Comment: @akuryo No problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

> - A:Humans are at most 12 feet tall
> - B:Humans are at most 9 feet tall

We have:

- A:= $\quad\forall h\in \operatorname{Humans}: \operatorname{tallness}(h)\leq 12$
- B:= $\quad\forall h\in \operatorname{Humans}: \operatorname{tallness}(h)\leq 9$

That is that neither statements' truth *requires* that the tallest possible human is of their given height, only that no human is taller that it.

So $B$ does not contradict $A$.   In fact there *is* a material implication: $B\to A$.   It is sufficient to know that if humans are at most $9$ feet tall, then we know humans are at most $12$ feet tall.